# Which keyword its talking about? ( parent = dict(globals or (), **vars) TypeError: keywords must be strings)

Tags: python, scripting, jinja2

I am trying to make a dictionary using excel data (key, values) to use that dictionary as context for rendering a .docx file. If I manually insert `context= { 'key':'value'}` it works but I want the context to be a dictionary made up of my excel data, when I tried to do that it shows the error, which is pointing to  `doc.render(context)` this line of my following code.

```
from jinja2.filters import contextfilter
import pandas as pd
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import jinja2
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime("%H%M%S")


TemplateName= "dorpotro mullayon template" 
SourceExcelName="Engine"
ExcelKeyColumnName= "Key"
ExcelValueColumnName= "Example"
OutputName= TemplateName + " " + time + '.docx'

print(OutputName)

doc=DocxTemplate(f'{TemplateName}.docx')

note_data = pd.read_excel(f"{SourceExcelName}.xlsx")

context= dict(zip(note_data[ExcelKeyColumnName],note_data[ExcelValueColumnName])) 



doc.render(context)
doc.save(OutputName)
```

the error is like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Raisul Not to upload\model desktop\compressed\Meettings\total project.py", line 33, in <module>
    doc.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Raisul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py", line 317, in render
    xml_src = self.build_xml(context, jinja_env)
  File "C:\Users\Raisul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py", line 272, in build_xml
    xml = self.render_xml_part(xml, self.docx._part, context, jinja_env)
  File "C:\Users\Raisul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py", line 221, in render_xml_part
    dst_xml = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Raisul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1299, in render
    ctx = self.new_context(dict(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Raisul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1395, in new_context
    return new_context(
  File "C:\Users\Raisul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py", line 119, in new_context
    parent = dict(globals or (), **vars)
TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

Comment: "If I manually insert context= { 'key':'value'} it works but I want the context to be a dictionary made up of my excel data, when I tried to do that it shows the error" Well, did you try *checking the dictionary that you get* from your excel data? Does it meet the requirements? If you don't know what the requirements are, did you try reading the documentation to find out? My best guess is that the keys of the dictionary you get need to be strings because somewhere along the lines that dictionary is getting used as `**kwargs` for something.

Comment: Yes I printed the context dictionary which I get from the excel and that is just as I want. And I actually ran a simpler version of same thing with a straight-forward data(just one row) set, that worked fine , just after I tried to get the 'not so straight forward (approximately 10 rows of key value pairs)' data, this error showed up.

Comment: Can you manually build the exact same data and reproduce the error? If so, can you modify the data piece by piece to figure out what causes the problem? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . We don't have your .docx file so there is no way we can test this ourselves.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly `note_data[ExcelKeyColumnName]` contains non-string values. This is being raised because you try to double-splat a dictionary with non-string keys. Try `dict(**{1:2})` or `def foo(**kwargs): pass` then `foo(**{1:2})`

Comment: after reading the comment of @KarlKnechtel "Can you manually build the same data and reproduce the error? If so, can you modify the data piece by piece to figure out what causes the problem?", I tried to manually check if the dictionary I am getting from excel data is erroneous or not, I found a `{...., nan: nan,.....}` basically that was making the problem. Now the problem is solved. So the knowledge I am taking away is, **while taking input from excel no key-value pair in other words no rows should be left blank**, Please suggest If its wrong take away.

Comment: Since the data is coming from an actual Excel spreadsheet (and not a plain CSV), you should probably spend some time thinking about a) how Excel decides on the type of data stored in each cell; b) how that's represented in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
doc.render(context=context)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33193594)